# Cakephp 3 saving data to a join table and a table associated to that join table

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to save data this way: 'Orders'->'OrdersFoods'->'OrdersFoodsChanges'. Where OrdersFoodsTable is a join table (Orders - Foods).

Why do I want to do so? Table OrdersFoods contains information about ordered foods (ids), but I would like to save additional data about every ingredient used for that food in particular order. That's why I've created additional table (OrdersFoodsChanges) with id from table OrdersFoods.

I can save data to a joined table but not to another table (OrdersFoodsChangesTable).

I've tried to do it the simplest way:

```
            $order = $this->Orders->patchEntity($order, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => [
                'Foods._joinData.OrdersFoodsChanges'
                //'Foods.OrdersFoods.OrdersFoodsChanges'
            ]
```

but with no luck.

patchEntity object

```
object(Admin\Model\Entity\Order) {

'user_id' => (int) 1,
'city' => '',
'postal_code' => '',
'street' => '',
'house' => '',
'phone' => '',
'foods' => [
    (int) 0 => object(Admin\Model\Entity\Food) {

        'id' => (int) 15,
        'name' => 'Royal',
        'price' => (float) 15,
        'category_id' => (int) 2,
        'photo_id' => (int) 69,
        'shop_id' => (int) 1,
        'favorite' => false,
        'vat' => (int) 23,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => (int) 0,
        '_joinData' => object(Admin\Model\Entity\OrdersFood) {

            'quantity' => (int) 1,
            'orders_foods_changes' => [
                (int) 0 => object(Admin\Model\Entity\OrdersFoodsChange) {

                    'component_quantity' => (int) 25,
                    'component_id' => (int) 1,
                    'order_food_id' => (int) 1,
                    'type' => 'ADD',
                    'element_num' => (int) 1,
                    '[new]' => true,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [
                        'component_quantity' => true,
                        'component_id' => true,
                        'order_food_id' => true,
                        'type' => true,
                        'element_num' => true
                    ],
                    '[original]' => [],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'Admin.OrdersFoodsChanges'

                }
            ],
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'quantity' => true,
                'orders_foods_changes' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Admin.OrdersFoods'

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [
            '_joinData' => true
        ],
        '[original]' => [
            '_joinData' => [
                'quantity' => '1',
                'orders_foods_changes' => [
                    (int) 0 => [
                        'component_quantity' => (int) 25,
                        'component_id' => (int) 1,
                        'order_food_id' => (int) 1,
                        'type' => 'ADD',
                        'element_num' => (int) 1,
                        'id' => (int) 2
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Admin.Foods'

    }
],
'price' => (float) 15,
'shop_id' => (int) 1,
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [
    'user_id' => true,
    'type' => true,
    'city' => true,
    'postal_code' => true,
    'street' => true,
    'house' => true,
    'phone' => true,
    'foods' => true,
    'price' => true,
    'shop_id' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Admin.Orders'
```

}

As I can see from sql log Cake does not even tries to save anything to a last table.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What is the actual issue? What doesn't work? Error message? Model examples?

Comment: @awons No error while saving. I've just edited my post. My guess is that something is wrong with OrdersFoodsChanges entity. Some stupid mistake. I've added "fields" manualy in cotroller ex.: $this->request->data['foods'][0]['_joinData']['orders_foods_changes'][0]['component_id'] = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem was that by default cake save method makes only one level association.

> By default the save() method will also save one level of associations

When I've added associated it all went well.

```
        if ($this->Orders->save($order, [
            'associated' => ['Foods._joinData.OrdersFoodsChanges']
        ]))
```